# Shrink to fit a div vertically inside a window

Tags: javascript, css

I want a window that shrinks to fit the current window.  This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/11n8hL1y/24/) is very close to what I want to achieve.   To use it simply resize the output window vertically until the blue line gets cutoff.  Then reverse the process. However, I want it to continue to work even if there is padding and/or other elements on the page.

```
<div id="output"></div>

<div id="sample" class="sampleClass">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello</div>  
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello</div>
</div>

window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);


var originalHeight = document.getElementById('sample').offsetHeight;
var safeBuffer = 15;

function updateDimensions(){
    var node = document.getElementById('sample');
    var windowDimensions = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};
    var dimensions = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  var nodeBottom = dimensions.bottom;
  var nodeHeight = node.offsetHeight;

  var nodeTop = dimensions.top;
  var windowHeight = windowDimensions.height;

  var windowIsCutOff = windowHeight <= nodeBottom;
  var windowIsShowing = windowHeight >= nodeTop;

  console.log('windowHeight: ' + windowHeight + ' safeBuffer: ' + safeBuffer);
  console.log('nodeHeight: ' + nodeHeight + ' originalHeight: ' + originalHeight);
  var nodeCanGrowBigger =  (windowHeight - safeBuffer - 10) > nodeHeight && nodeHeight < originalHeight;
  console.log('nodeCanGrowBigger: ' + nodeCanGrowBigger);

  if(windowIsShowing && windowIsCutOff) {
     console.log('do work');
     shrinkWindow(nodeBottom, windowHeight, nodeHeight);
  }

  if(nodeCanGrowBigger){
    growWindow(nodeBottom, windowHeight, nodeHeight);
  }
}

function growWindow(nodeBottom, windowHeight, nodeHeight){
  var node = document.getElementById('sample');
  var originalHeight = nodeHeight;
  var offset = nodeHeight - windowHeight;
  var newHeight;
  if(offset >= -safeBuffer && offset <= safeBuffer){
   newHeight = originalHeight;
  }
  else if(offset >= 0){
    newHeight = originalHeight + offset;
    console.log('positive calculation originalHeight: ' + originalHeight + ' offset: ' + offset + ' for newHeight: ' + newHeight);
    }else{
    newHeight = originalHeight - offset;
    console.log('negative', newHeight);
  }
  node.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
  console.log('height attmpted changed to', newHeight);
  console.log('height offset', node.offsetHeight);
  console.log('height style', node.style.height);
}

function shrinkWindow(nodeBottom, windowHeight, nodeHeight) {
    var node = document.getElementById('sample');
  var originalHeight = nodeHeight;
  //console.log('originalHeight', originalHeight);
  //console.log('nodeBottom:' + nodeBottom + ' windowHeight: ' + windowHeight);
  var offset = nodeHeight - windowHeight;
  //console.log('offset', offset);
  var newHeight;
  if(offset >= -safeBuffer && offset <= safeBuffer){
   newHeight = originalHeight - (safeBuffer + 1);
  }
  else if(offset >= 0){
    newHeight = originalHeight - offset;
    //console.log('positive calculation originalHeight: ' + originalHeight + ' offset: ' + offset + ' for newHeight: ' + newHeight);
    }else{
    newHeight = originalHeight + offset;
    //console.log('negative', newHeight);
  }
  node.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
  /*
  console.log('height attmpted changed to', newHeight);
  console.log('height offset', node.offsetHeight);
  console.log('height style', node.style.height);
  */
}


.sampleClass {
 padding: 0px;
 height: 300px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 border: solid blue;
 //margin: 10px 300px 10px 25px;
 margin: 0px
 position: 'relative'
}
```

This JavaScript solution I came up with feels overly complex. It doesn't solve for things like padding, or more content on the page either. Can I solve this problem with plain old CSS or a JS extension?

I know [Kendo ui](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui) has this effect in their Modal windows (at least in the 5 year old version we use).  I'm not open to using Kendo.

Comment: Instead of a height, wouldn't it be enough to just give the .simpleClass a max-height?

Comment: @moesphemie I wish that were enough.  Doing so gives me a very different effect.  The whitespace is gone and the scrollbars never display.  Plus adding more content to the page would result in a static piece of content.  https://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/wd4p0ytm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to say if this will work for your situation ... Look at the following touch-up. It could use more work, but I think it will point you in the direction I was heading:

```
function updateDimensions(){
  var node = document.getElementById('sample');
  var windowDimensions = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};
  var dimensions = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  var nodeBottom = dimensions.bottom;
  var nodeHeight = node.offsetHeight;

  var nodeTop = dimensions.top;
  var windowHeight = windowDimensions.height;

  var windowIsCutOff = windowHeight <= nodeBottom;
  var windowIsShowing = windowHeight >= nodeTop;

  console.log('windowHeight: ' + windowHeight + ' safeBuffer: ' + safeBuffer);
  console.log('nodeHeight: ' + nodeHeight + ' originalHeight: ' + originalHeight);
  var nodeCanGrowBigger =  (windowHeight - safeBuffer - 10) > nodeHeight && nodeHeight < originalHeight;
  console.log('nodeCanGrowBigger: ' + nodeCanGrowBigger);

  if ( (windowIsShowing && windowIsCutOff) || nodeCanGrowBigger ) {
     growWindow(nodeTop, windowHeight, nodeHeight);
  }
}

function growWindow(nodeTop, windowHeight, nodeHeight){
  var node = document.getElementById('sample');
  var offset = windowHeight - ( nodeTop + nodeHeight + safeBuffer );
  var newHeight = nodeHeight + offset;
  node.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}
```

As you can see, I use nodeTop instead of nodeBottom for the calculation and I used the combination of nodeTop, nodeHeight and safeBuffer to indicate the bottom of the node, then used the difference of that with the window for the offset. This should work regardless of whether you're shrinking or expanding the window.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [version](https://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/11n8hL1y/31/) most like Kendo UI:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);

var node = document.getElementById('sample');
var style = node.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(node);
var marginTop = style.marginTop.replace("px", "");
marginTop = parseInt(marginTop, 10);
var innerNode = document.getElementById('inner');
var innerNodeStyle = innerNode.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(innerNode);
var innerMarginTop = innerNodeStyle.marginTop.replace("px", "");
innerMarginTop = parseInt(innerMarginTop, 10);
var innerMarginBottom = innerNodeStyle.marginBottom.replace("px", "");
innerMarginBottom = parseInt(innerMarginBottom, 10);
var totalInnerMarginSize = innerMarginTop + innerMarginBottom;
var safeBuffer = 0;
//if(marginTop < 20){
  safeBuffer = 20;
//}
var originalHeight = node.offsetHeight + marginTop + safeBuffer;


function updateDimensions(){
  var windowDimensions = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};
  var dimensions = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  //console.log('totalInnerMarginSize: ' + totalInnerMarginSize);
  var cutoffPoint = marginTop + node.offsetHeight + safeBuffer + totalInnerMarginSize ;
  var nodeTop = dimensions.top;
  var innerNodeDimensions = innerNode.getBoundingClientRect();
  var innerNodeTop = innerNodeDimensions.top;
  var innerNodeHeight = innerNodeDimensions.height;
  //console.log('innerNodeHeight: ' + innerNodeHeight);
  var windowHeight = windowDimensions.height;
  console.log('windowHeight: ' + windowHeight + ' cutoffPoint: ' + cutoffPoint);
  var windowIsCutOff = windowHeight <= cutoffPoint;
  //console.log('windowHeight: ' + windowHeight + ' nodeTop: ' + nodeTop);
  var windowIsShowing = windowHeight > nodeTop;


  var nodeCanGrowBigger =  windowHeight > cutoffPoint && cutoffPoint < originalHeight;
  //console.log('nodeCanGrowBigger: ' + nodeCanGrowBigger);
  //console.log('windowHeight: ' + windowHeight + ' cutoffPoint: ' + cutoffPoint
              //+ ' originalHeight: ' + originalHeight);

    //console.log('windowIsShowing: ' + windowIsShowing + ' windowIsCutOff: ' + windowIsCutOff + ' nodeCanGrowBigger: ' + nodeCanGrowBigger);
  if ( (windowIsShowing && windowIsCutOff) || nodeCanGrowBigger ) {
     resizeWindow(innerNodeHeight, windowHeight, cutoffPoint);
  }
}

function resizeWindow(innerHeight, windowHeight, cutoffPoint){
    //console.log('innerHeight: ' + innerHeight + ' windowHeight: ' + windowHeight
               //+ ' cutoffPoint: ' + cutoffPoint);

  var newHeight = innerHeight - (cutoffPoint - windowHeight);
  innerNode.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}

<div id="output"></div>

<div id="sample" class="sampleClass">
  <h1>
   Header
  </h1>
    <div id="inner">
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>hello</div>  
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>hello</div>
   </div>
  <h1>
  footer
  </h1>
</div>

.sampleClass {
 padding: 10px;
 //height: 300px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 border: solid blue;
 //margin: 10px 300px 10px 25px;
 margin: 70px;
 position: 'relative'
}

#inner{
  position: 'relative';
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```